# Coding a "trial run" into an iPhone App that connects to the AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have created an application and I have purchased an account in AppStore.

I wish to configure the app such that it will run for free twice and after that the user will have to purchase the full version. I want to implement the purchase of the full version inside the trial version (using in-app purchases).

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640944/iphone-in-app-purchases-for-free-trials

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple does not allow trial software in the App Store. You can have 'lite' versions of your applications, but Apple requires that they are fully functional applications that do not expire and are not simply advertisements for your for-pay app.

Once you figure out what type of features you want to offer in a 'lite' version, one thing you could do to offer an in-place upgrade for customers in to use the in-app purchase mechanism. Apple now allows free applications to sell in-app purchases. So you could have an app call 'Foo' and inside 'Foo' you could have a menu option to unlock additional features, which would bring them to the in-app purchases dialogs where they could pay you to unlock more content of the app.

Check out Apple's tips & tricks for App Store submission: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/appstoretips/

There (listed on Sept. 18th, 2009) you will find a tip titled *Just Right "Lite"* that reads:

> Using a "Lite" version to show how it
>   feels to use what you make and what
>   kinds of things your app can do is
>   definitely a good way to find
>   customers who will pay for the full
>   version of your application. But store
>   shoppers tell us it only works if you
>   follow a few simple rules:
>
> - Make sure the functionality you decide to include is complete. Battles
>     that require weapons only available in
>     the full version, for instance, are
>     annoying and irritating instead of
>     enticing.
> - Don't set time limits on your "Lite" version, either for run times
>     or life times. Applications that will
>     only run for a set number of minutes
>     per session, or that expire altogether
>     after some period of time, don't
>     recruit customers so much as leave a
>     bad taste in their mouths.
> - Only display the UI for what your "Lite" version will do. Grayed out
>     menu commands, "more track/car
>     choices" you can see but not select,
>     etc. makes your "Lite" version feel
>     more like a commercial than a product,
>     and an annoying and ineffective one at
>     that.
> - Do include information about your full application, including an option
>     to buy, in either your application's
>     About section or on the splash screen.
>     Just make sure the option to continue
>     using the "Lite" version is there as
>     well. A good impression lasts forever.
>
> It's important to follow these simple
>   rules not only to create a better user
>   experience, but also because your app
>   will be returned to you by the App
>   Review Team for modification if it is
>   found to have time limits, incomplete
>   functionality, or disabled
>   functionality.

The most relevent part of that text for yourself and your proposed App design is the last sentence that contains "... your app will be **returned to you by the App Review Team** for modification if it is found to have **time limits**..."

Comment: my app is same as you are talking,
but one twist is there,

first version of app will allow user to use app for 2 trials then the features will be disabled,

then user will have two options:
1)Extend app for 10 mote trial so all feature will get activated upon payment,
2)Or user can have full version that will work for n number  of trial upon payment,

how to code this payment things in application ?

Comment: @abc the "one twist" you are talking about would be deemed a trial feature by Apple, and would therefore be in violation of their application guidelines and rejected from the App Store.

Comment: can you give me apple's reference that describes this policy ?

Comment: No problem, I've edited my post to include the relevant source of information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good walkthrough on adding in-app features to your app.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/

Comment: hi John i read this blog:

but could not understand the concept of product reference,

how to create product references ? 
i mean i have a product "A", still not uploadded in app store, 
i have 3 features in it, say x.y.z 
now the prize for each one is different how inividually buy this features..?